# Is there a way to instantiate a new Control, without adding it to the UserForm?

Tags: excel, vba

I would prefer to create a `Control` object that does not belong to any particular `Form`, sort of as a proxy for other `Form Control` objects. The `Control` would need to be a `TextBox`.

I haven't used Visual Basic in many years, and have never touched VBA. So, my question isn't about whether or not this is advised, but rather whether it's even possible. :D

What I have now is:

```
Controls.Add("Forms.TextBox.1")
```

This however, adds the `Control` to the `UserForm`. Which is fine, I guess, because I can also just turn it invisible, but I'm just curious.

On the other hand, `Dim ctl As New Control` does not specify it should be a `TextBox`.

Where is the golden mean in between?

Comment: Controls need to be on a form/worksheet.  Just like you can't (eg) do something like `Dim rng As New Range`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gonna stick my neck out and say

```
Dim o As MSForms.TextBox ' or Object if no reference to 'Microsoft Forms 2.0 Object Library'
Set o = CreateObject("Forms.TextBox.1")
o.Text = "Hello World"
Debug.Print TypeName(o) & ", " & o.TextLength
```

Prints `TextBox, 11` to the Immediate window.

Comment: Very nice, that is all that I needed.